# Laravel forms, multiselect saving into different rows in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a multiselect, code is below for the multiselect within my blade.

```
    {{Form::label('server_id', 'Server')}}      
    <select multiple="multiple" name="server_id[]" id="server_id" class="form-control form-control-md">
        @foreach($servers as $key => $name)
            <option value="{{$key}}">{{$name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select
```

The issue I am running into is I need each of the selected values to be saved within a different row in the database. As you can see right now the `key` is being saved witihin the `server_id[]` 
(Right now it throws an error on save because of unsupported operand type)

But I need each of the items within server_id[] to be saved within their own database entry so they can be easily referred to later. How could one go about doing that, I cant seem to figure it out?

If you need my migrations or controllers I would be happy to add them!

EDIT::  Controller to store after form submission

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'server_id' => 'required',
        ]);

        $app = Apps::orderby('created_at','desc')->first();
        $app_id = $app->id;

        Helpers::storeAppServer($request, $app_id);

        return redirect('dashboard')->with('success', 'Application Server Updated');
    }
```

Helper:

```
public static function storeAppServer(Request $request, $app_id){
        $appserver = new AppServer;
        $appserver->app_id = $app_id;
        $appserver->server_id = $request->input('server_id') + 1;
        $appserver->save();
}
```

Comment: Post your controller code as well.

Comment: Controller is added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `server_id` is a multi select field, so it will be posted as an array. And can be treated as array in Helper function `storeAppServer`. Iterate all values in `server_id` or `$serverIds` and save them one by one in database.

**Code:**

```
public static function storeAppServer(Request $request, $app_id) 
{
    $serverIds = $request->input('server_ids');
    if (is_array($serverIds)) {
        foreach ($serverIds as $serverId) {
            $appserver = new AppServer;
            $appserver->app_id = $app_id;
            $appserver->server_id = $serverId + 1;
            $appserver->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited your code slightly so that it worked, I just needed to create a new instance of the AppServer model on each iteration of the foreach also and add app_id to each Instance.